# Let $A$ be an orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix. Show that $\|A\vec x\|=\|A^{-1}\vec x\|$ for any vector $x$ in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an orthogonal $n\times n$ matrix. Show that $\|A\vec x\|=\|A^{-1}\vec x\|$ for any vector $\vec x$ in $\mathbb R^2$

I want to show that $\|A\vec x\|=\|A^{-1}\vec x\|=\|\vec x\|$

I tried to show that since $A^TA=I$, then using $A^T=A^{-1}$,

$\|A^{-1}\vec x\|=(A^{-1}\vec x)\cdot(A^{-1}\vec x)=(A^{-1}\vec x)^T(A^{-1}\vec x)=\vec x^T(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}\vec x=\vec x^T(A^{T})^TA^{-1}\vec x=\vec x^TAA^{-1}\vec x$.

I got stuck here since by definition $A^TA\neq AA^T$ (or is it)?

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: $AA^{-1}=A^{-1}A=I$

Comment: @user95087 : I don't understand what the problem is.  Everything you have is correct (except a typo), you just need to use $AA^{-1}=I$ as vadim123 wrote and finish up.  Your typo is that your displayed equation should begin with the _square_ of the norm of the vector.  That gives you $\|A \mathbf{v}\| = \|\mathbf{v}\|$ if $A$ is orthogonal.  Now prove $A^{-1}$ is also orthogonal, so $\|A^{-1} \mathbf{v}\| = \|\mathbf{v}\|$.

Comment: @user95087 : I don't know offhand if there is an easier way to prove $\|A\mathbf{x}\|=\|A^{-1}\mathbf{x}\|$ for all $\mathbf{x}$ (which is apparently all you had to do) without proving $\|A\mathbf{x}\|=\|A^{-1}\mathbf{x}\|=\|\mathbf{x}\|$ for all $\mathbf{x}$.

Comment: @user95087 : by the way, since $A$ is orthogonal, $A^T A = I$ (this is often used as a definition of orthogonal), and by properties of matrix inverses, $A A^T = I = A^T A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You need the fact

> a matrix $Q$ is orthogonal if its transpose is equal to its inverse:
>   $$Q^\mathrm{T}=Q^{-1}, \,$$
>   which entails
>   $$ Q^\mathrm{T} Q = Q Q^\mathrm{T} = I.$$

Comment: I think it's much more common to define orthogonality by the formula at the bottom instead of the other way around, even though it's all the same.

Comment: @GitGud: I think the first one is easier to recall. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Ah thanks I realize my mistake now.

Comment: @user95087: you are welcome.